# ios8 w/swift iPad only UX/UI design

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, metal

i'm implementing an app, iPad, iOS8.1+ in swift/metal, landscape only

the main view has 3 containers with a left pullout/slideout/drawer of icons for launching subprocesses

the left slide out will only contain icons no text for things like database access, microphone, stencil overlay, video record, airplay, iTunes, Dropbox, user config, etc

the 3 main containers, 
view 1 will hold a 3d rendered model this will take up 75% horz/vert

view 2 will hold a 2d side projection of the rendered model in view 1 ( aka side or top view)

and

view 3 will hold a either detailed subview of something that is choosen in view 1 or view 2
                or a pdf document
                or a webcontainer

i am concerned about threading as this app will be asynchronously pulling in large amount of data, rendering via gpu buffer and then pushing results via airplay to a video screen.

that being said there are no "Metal View Containers" but there is GLKView, SceneKit for 3d/2d.

do i need to define 3 generic container views and build them up? or is this another way to chop up the existing GLview for Metal?

does anyone have such a metal container already built?

thanks for any positive help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `GLKView` and `GLKViewController` are not meant to work with Metal even though they both execute on the GPU. If using Metal, must create your own Metal `View` and Metal `ViewController`. This is because OpenGL is done with `CAEAGLLayer` and Metal is done with `CAMetalLayer`. I don't know if anyone has done this. Most likely Apple will create these classes on the next iteration of the SDK.

For the 3 container, you can create 3 separate layers, but its more efficient to manually tell metal to draw 3 separate sections. However, this is not an easy task.

I don't think you have to worry about the threading as long as you don't mess with Metal buffer data during execution. Metal's buffer data are not copied (you could) when pass to the GPU. OpenGL buffer data are copied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Could you quantify how much efficient to manually have metal draw 3 separate sections vs separate layers?  would i get 20% more fps?  40%?

Comment: Can't really estimate. It all depend on how it's implemented. The efficiency comes when you are not creating multiple rendering passes and drawable textures. You can create 1 drawable context and 1 command buffer and use multiple rendering pipelines with different view ports. However, if easy to maintain the sections with layers, do that. Sacrifice little of performance.